# leaflet javascript - how to clearTimeout a setTimeout on a marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, leaflet, cleartimeout

I am adding markers like this to my map:

```
 map.addLayer(l), setTimeout(function() {
      map.removeLayer(l)
 }, 1e4),
```

which removes after 10 seconds each marker again. Now I would like to achieve that when the user clicks during those 10 seconds on a marker that the market stays visible on the map. So far I have:

```
l.on('click', function(e) {

console.log(e);
console.log(e.layer._leaflet_id);
console.log(l);

clearTimeout(e.layer._leaflet_id);

});
```

But it does now work. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: `setTimeout` returns an ID. You need to call `clearTimeout` with that ID.

Comment: @MikeC - i try to do this by calling clearTimeout(e.layer._leaflet_id); which has the id of the setTimeout function (l). I try also everything thing  else but those markers are disappearing :(

Comment: Are you sure you're saving it to `_leaflet_id`? The top section of your code doesn't seem to indicate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel the setTimeout by calling the clearTimeout using the relevant ID.

```
    var myVar;
    timeout_init();

    function timeout_init() {
        myVar = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.marker').hide();
            },5000);
    }

$( ".marker" ).click(function() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
});
```

[See example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cc67eku/)